# Convert mixture of values and ranges to a single array within a UDF

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I'm trying build up one array from the contents of another in an Excel Macro (specifically this UDF)

```
Sub Call_Probably()
```

Debug.Print PROBABLY(1, "a", "b", Range("A2", "A3"))
End Sub

```
Public Function PROBABLY(ParamArray inputArray() As Variant) As String
Dim inElement As Variant
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim subcell As Range
'convert ranges to values


'creating a new array from the mixture of ranges and values in the input array
ReDim outputArray(0)
For Each inElement In inputArray
'Normal values get copied from the input UDF to an output array, ranges get split up then appended
    If TypeName(inElement) = "Range" Then
        For Each subcell In inElement
            outputArray(UBound(outputArray)) = subcell
            ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) + 1)
        Next subcell
    Else
    'Stick the element on the end of an output array
        outputArray(UBound(outputArray)) = inElement
        ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) + 1)
    End If
Next inElement
ReDim Preserve outputArray(UBound(outputArray) - 1)

PROBABLY = outputArray(outputArray(0))
End Function
```

What I'm trying to do is to cycle through the elements of `inputArray()`, and for simple values (numbers, words) I put that value into an `outputArray`, for ranges of values (like A2 of B5:B6) I cycle through *that range* and stick the `subcell`'s value onto the end of my `outputArray`. I think the problem is that `redim` clears the array contents, so I'm only left with the last result stuck on the end.

Also I don't like `If TypeName(inElement) = "Range"`; it assumes that the only thing a user can enter is a value (e.g. 1, "cat", TRUE) or a range(e.g. A1, A1:B3). What if the user enters an array formula, such that one of the elements of `inputArray` is {1,1,0,0}. That's not a simple single value, nor is it a range - so maybe it isn't accounted for in the UDF?Like if I enter

```
{=PROBABLY(G5,"a","b",IF(A2:A3<0,1,A2:A3))}
```

I can't test this because I don't know how to call my UDF with an array formula input from within vba, therefore I can't debug it.

Ideally what I want is for all of the elements referenced in the `ParamArray` argument of my UDF to be split up and recombined in an exploded fashion. I imagine `=SUM()` works this way, as `{=SUM(2,A2:A3,IF(ISTEXT(B1:B3),1,0))}` would be perfectly acceptable, and it contains a mixture of values ranges and arrays. I want that functionality.

---

### Round 2

Ok, I updated the code with `ReDim Preserve`, and fixed a few spelling mistakes etc. But as suspected the formula can't deal with an array as an input. I checked an array's `TypeName` and it is `variant`, so won't be picked up by my `If [...] = "Range" Then` line. But it also throws an error when put through the standard `Else` code. So how can I add that array too?

Comment: redim preserve retains the values in the array

Comment: use `ReDim Preserve` instead of `ReDim`

Comment: in addition to redim preserve, check your spelling - Proably = outputArray(outputArray(0)).  "Proably" should be "Probably"

Comment: Probably true... and now that I can debug properly I've noticed a number of other glaring errors